# SQL Query to get data from same table different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to get data from Same table by checking two different columns? Here is the sample wherein i have a table A which has records as shown below

```
Col.a Col.b Col.c
-----------------
X     Y      Z
Y     X      Z
```

There are 3 columns col.a, col.b and col.c and some of them have records as seen below wherein Col.a of one row = col.b of another and vice versa, The only id common among both the rows is col.c...

i want to get list of all distinct col.c ids which exhibit this behaviour.. i tried inner join but was of no help

Please suggest

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you want to do. If you want all information from col.a and col.b where the value of col.c is a certain value just use SELECT * FROM table WHERE col.c = z. INNER JOIN only works between mltuple tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why inner join are not help?

```
create table t_col (a varchar2(1),b varchar2(1),c varchar2(1)); 

insert into t_col (a,b,c) values('x','y','z'); 
insert into t_col (a,b,c) values('y','x','z'); 

select distinct col.c 
from t_col col 
join t_col col2 on Col.a = Col2.b and Col.b = col2.a and Col.c = Col2.c;
```

or

```
select distinct col.c 
from t_col col 
where exists (select null 
                from t_col col2 
               where Col.a = Col2.b 
                 and Col.b = col2.a 
                 and Col.c = Col2.c);
```

or if we want to check nulls

```
select distinct col.c 
from t_col col 
where exists (select null 
                from t_col col2 
               where decode(Col.a,Col2.b,1,0) = 1
                 and decode(Col.b,col2.a,1,0) = 1
                 and decode(Col.c,Col2.c,1,0) = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c
    FROM A
    WHERE a IN (
            SELECT b
            FROM A
            )
```